# Issues when reading from a database in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sqlite

I am making an iPhone app for a school project that reads and writes to a database. I have managed to get my code to write to it but it won't read. Below is the code I'm using to read:

```
NSString * paths=[self getWritableDBPath];
const char *dbpath =  [paths UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT questionright, totalquestions, FROM results", nil];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            //code...
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }


    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Here is getWritableDBPath:

```
-(NSString *) getWritableDBPath {
NSString *myDB = @"appData.db";

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:myDB];

}
```

**The reason it doesn't work is that the sqlite3_prepare_v2  if statement is never satisfied.**

When I write to the database I copy it to documents.

I am quite sure the results table exists as I am able to write to it. Here is the original sql statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Questions";
CREATE TABLE "Questions" ("QuestionID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "Question" TEXT, "RightAnswer" TEXT, "WrongAnswer1" TEXT, "WrongAnswer2" TEXT, "Done" BOOL, "Catagory" TEXT, "Audio" INTEGER);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Results";
CREATE TABLE "Results" ("ResultID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "QuestionRight" INTEGER, "TotalQuestions" INTEGER, "Catagory" TEXT);
```

I did find a similar question on here but didn't think the answers were that relevant to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What value is the `sqlite_prepare_v2` function returning? Compare it to a list of error codes found [here](http://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) and post the answer. Also, don't use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` when you don't have a format. Just use `const char *query_stmt = "SELECT questionright, totalquestions, FROM results";`

Comment: sqlite_prepare_v2 returns a value of 1.Thanks for the advice on using const char.

Comment: 1 is `SQLITE_ERROR` which I'm afraid is a really generic error code: ***The SQLITE_ERROR result code is a generic error code that is used when no other more specific error code is available.***

Comment: If the table it was trying to read from was empty would it give this message? And is there a way to open the data base that is stored in documents to check if it has been populated?

Comment: I don't think reading from an empty table should cause this issue, but don't quote me on that. If you want to open and view an SQLite database file use [this OS X App](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sqlpro-for-sqlite-read-only/id635299994?mt=12). For more info on `sqlite_prepare` see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html). I'm sorry I haven't been more use.

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND! The issue was that i had and extra comma before the FROM in my sql statement. Thanks anyway for your time and help.

Comment: Ah, yea it's easy to overlook things like that. Looking at the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) it seems you can get a precise error message by doing this: `if (sqlite...... == SQLITE_OK) {} else {const char *error = sqlite3_errmsg(db); NSLog(@"%s", error);}` If you make this call straight after an error you will get an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want my advice, don't use the sqlite c libraries directly if you don't really need that, you can use FMDB library and get rid of all the c headache 
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

You can simply do it like this

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"your full db path in documents goes here"];
if (![db open]) {
    return;
}
FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"Your query goes here"];
if ([s next]) {
    int totalCount = [s intForColumn:@"totalCount"];
}
```